# Spring Integration Sftp Outbound Gateway to IBM mainframe

Tags: sftp, spring-integration, outbound

I have reviewed [spring integration sftp mainframe :failed to write file; nested exception is 3: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877027/spring-integration-sftp-mainframe-failed-to-write-file-nested-exception-is-3), but still cannot sftp a file to a remote mainframe.

If I use a command line to sftp to my account, my login directory is:
/home/users/snoopy

From here, I can issue the command "put filename //#12345" and the file is transferred.  I cannot figure out how to specify "//#12345" in my outbound-gateway. Are there some sftp-options you can add to specify this same command? Does it get added to the expression?, ie expression="payload.filename + ???"

The current remote-directory is /home/users/snoopy, so I can put to that directory without any issues, I just can't get it to //#12345

If I try remote-directory set to /home/users/snoopy//#12345, or /home/users/snoopy/#12345, those paths do not exist

Here is my gateway configuration:

```
<sftp outbound-gateway id="sftpOutbound"
session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
request-channel="sftpOut"
command="put"
expression="payload.filename"
remote-directory="/home/users/snoopy"
remote-filename-generator="fileNameGenerator"
use-temporary-file-name="false"
reply-channel="successChannel"/>
```

With this configuration, I can send the file to /home/users/snoopy, I just haven't figured out how to get it to //#12345

Comment: Please, share the confg to help us to figure out an issue.

Comment: I just added the configuration.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Thanks. Let me ask additional questions. Is `//#12345` a sub-dir?

Comment: When I ssh to the box, I cannot find such a directory.  The file format I am sending is #12345.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, which I understand the mainframe should recognize and automatically route it